# Trying to get property of non-object wp-includes/template.php on line 675 when used load_template()

Tags: wordpress, templates, plugins

I have a template file in my theme folder and included this file to a plugin using load_template(). And am getting Trying to get property of non-object wp-includes/template.php on line 675 notice.

My question is can we use load_template() to include a template file in plugin? When i used require_once instead of load_template() the error vanished.

Can you please clarify my doubt?

And also i have an another question, why some errors not appear on site?
I can view some errors when i make the WP_DEBUG set to true.